# Chocolate distribution problem with k-chocolates-at-once constraint

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, permutation

Question: N Chocolates are to be distributed among 3 children such that any of the child can have maximum of k chocolates at once. In how many ways can the chocolates be distributed?
**For example:**

**INPUT**:

```
k = 2
n = 2
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
maximum number of ways: 6
```

**Explanation**:

```
{[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]}
```

**INPUT**

```
k = 5 
n = 15
```

**OUPUT**:

```
maximum number of ways: 1
```

**Explanation**:

```
{[5, 5, 5]}
```

First I tried getting direct answer by formulating an equation using permutation and combination. I got this problem in an exam and there i formulated a formula which i don't exactly remember but it was somewhat like this:

```
for i in range(3+1):
  total += (-1)**(i)*comb(3, 1)*comb(n-i*(k+1)+2, 2)
```

This is what I remembered, but it is wrong.

Comment: This is a constrained version of the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  However, in this version there is an added constraint on the maximum number of cookies a given child can have.  On the other hand, the number of children is fixed at 3 so that might help.  In the absence of a closed-form solution, it shouldn't be hard to solve it recursively.

Comment: How is this related to Digital Signature Algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Say, we're giving the first kid `0 <= i <= k` chocolates. Then, our problem becomes a bit easier, splitting `M = N-i` chocolates between two kids.

Since the other kid cannot have more than `k`, the first kid can have anywhere between `max(0, M-k)` and `min(M, k)` pieces. So, the number of ways to split `M` chocolates between two kids is `max(min(M, k)-max(0, M-k)+1, 0)`.

Now in the 3-way distribution we consider giving the first kid `0..k` chocolates and sum the ways to distribute the rest:

```
# yes, that's the whole solution
sum(max(min(M, k)-max(0, M-k)+1, 0) for M in range(n-k, n+1))
```